# Why this is happening in the following code?

Tags: c++, g++, bitwise-operators

I am running this c++ program for swapping two numbers using g++ compiler in ubuntu.

```cpp
int a = 6, b = 9;
a = a ^ b ^ (b = a);
cout << a << " " << b;
```

and I am getting this output `9 6`. Here first `b` is processed (old value of b that is 9) before processing `b=a` part.

But when I run this program

```cpp
a = a ^ b + (b = a);
cout << a << " " << b;
```

I get `10 6` as output. It means here `b = a` part is processed first therefore the value of every `b` is now `6` hence it is giving output `10 6`.

can anybody explain why it is happening so?

Comment: This statement  a=a^b^(b=a); invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: For real where do these approaches keep coming from??

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Java guys, I bet ya.

Comment: Please don't use XOR for swapping variables.  It's a hack that only works for unsigned integers.  Use `std::swap` or write your own using a temporary variable.

Comment: You need sequencing points.  Do this instead:  `b ^= a; a ^= b; b ^= a;`  But since these are `int` values (rather than unsigned), the behavior is platform specific.  Use `std::swap` instead, which will likely be faster.

Comment: @Eljay answer in the answers section please.

Answer (score 4):

`a = a ^ b ^ (b = a)` involves undefined behavior because the order of evaluation is not specified. If all you want is to swap two integers, use `std::swap`:

```
using std::swap;
int a = 6, b = 9;
swap(a, b);
```

Comment: ...which is probably faster than the silly XOR swap.

Comment: Definitely [faster than XOR swap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm#Reasons_for_avoidance_in_practice).

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour of your code is *undefined*! `(b=a)` writes to `b`. There are also reads of `b` in that same expression `a^b^(b=a)`, and there are no *sequencing* points in that expression either.

The language does not define the behaviour of a read and write of the same variable in an unsequenced step.

Note for the avoidance of doubt, the parentheses do **not** specify an order of evaluation, but rather *grouping*.

P.S. XOR swap is silly, and probably slower than `std::swap`.